# How does Flutter maintain consistency without loosing its data on any orientation change?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, viewmodel

I have been coding into flutter and is wondering if there is any kind of ViewModel thing that is supported in Flutter.
Main purpose of VieModel (as per the use in Android) is to separate the Views from the data.
Also, in Android, if we are filling a form then, on the change of orientation, the data of the several columns is not loss(due to ViewModel), how can we achieve the same in Flutter.

PS: I have been using Flutter's **Form** widget with **FormTextField**, it maintains it's sate (my Question is how? & why?) 
Also, I have blank data when I come back to my Form with Navigator.pop() , why ?
Do I have to make some changeNotifier or ViewModel to sync up things?
How to Pre-fill my Form with model instance.

Comment: Please check these links, they might be of help to you:
1- https://medium.com/free-code-camp/app-architecture-mvvm-in-flutter-using-dart-streams-26f6bd6ae4b6


2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780392/mvvm-design-pattern-in-flutter

Comment: These pages are helpful in the above context, but could you really please tell how can i save the form state, and as to why is it getting reset when I pop back the Navigator ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter doesn't lose its data because it uses its own render engine (aka [skia](https://skia.org/))  normal flutter app has just one activity with 'Canvas' that render everything and because of that it gives flutter opportunity to save the state of all UI (because it's not native views just all widgets renders via canvas)

Comment: That explains the concept of pixel rendering, but could you really please tell how can i save the form state, and as to why is it getting reset when I pop back the Navigator ??

Comment: to save the text of your textField you can store text as variable and add a listener to textController so when the text changes it will update your variable